# Will already finished vs. will already been finished

Tags: future-perfect

**Situation:** At present, I am currently playing COC (Clash of Clan), then I go to sleep, then I wake up. I want to ask what is the difference between these two:

> After I wake up, the tower that I am upgrading **will already have** finished.

To

> After I wake up, the tower that I am upgrading **will already have been**
>    finished.

Note: If you spot any grammar mistake(s) in this particular sentences that I have written, please correct me, I really wanted to be fluent in English. Also, after I **woke up** or after I **wake up**?

Comment: The first question to answer is: are you talking about something that happened in the past, or something that will happen in the future?  Because "After I woke up" is in the past, but "will already have" is about in the future, so it's unclear what time you're talking about.

Comment: Let's say I am currently playing COC, then I go to sleep, next, I woke up. Am I missing a tense in woke up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the grammar of both sentences is confusing, because first you use **woke** (a past tense), and then you use **will** (a future tense).  If you are making a statement about a specific future time, use the simple present:  *By the time I **wake** up...*

As for the difference between

> will have finished

and

> will have been finished

**will have finished** is in the *active* voice: it means that the tower is the one performing the action of "finishing".  If you say "the tower will have finished", it makes me ask "Finished what?"

**will have been finished** is in the passive voice: it means that someone else is performing the action of "finishing" on the tower.  We can tell that it's in the passive because of *been*, which is the past participle of *to be*, and we use *(to have) been (past-participle)* to form the passive voice in a perfect tense.  This is probably the one you want to use, because it makes more sense to think of someone or something else completing the building of the tower.

If the difference is unclear, consider this example:

Active: By the time I wake up, my friend John **will have eaten**  (John has eaten something)
Passive: By the time I wake up, my friend John **will have *been* eaten** (Something ate John!)

Reference: [Passive voice](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/passive-voice/)

Comment: Got it! As for by the time, wake up, and the usage of future. This 'been' thing included as passive is what I hadn't understand before I asked this question.(is this sentence correct?) Also, you didn't include 'already' why is that? I would appreciate deeply if you answer both 2 of my questions here.

Comment: Hi, @JohnArvin - "already" doesn't really change the meaning of the sentence. That's why I didn't include it.  As for your other sentence, I would phrase it as "This 'been' thing *meaning* passive is what I hadn't *understood* before I asked this question."

Comment: OP has edited question according to your point 1, and this answer has become out-of-sync. I don't know if OP edit should be reverted, or this answer updated instead.